# Which use for non-inherited abstract classes?

Tags: java, oop

What does good practice tells us about non-inherited abstract classes ?

Is there a reason for them to exist  in a program not aiming at providing an API ? Could it make sense to systematically turn such classes into non-abstract classes? If so  in which cases ?

Comment: why down vote? I guess its a very valid question provided OP provides valid examples from Java API.

Comment: It could be my mistake to use the java tag on this question. I was actually wondering on a meta level

Comment: Well, I don't think this is answerable "on the meta level", because it is the specific syntax and semantics of specific programming languages that determine whether or not there are valid use-cases of abstract classes that you don't inherit from.

Comment: Another point ... beware of appealing to terms like "good practice" and "best practice" - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based/296546#296546 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: You can look at them as "to-be-extended" classes. No, it is not there to be turned to concrete classes. It is there to be extended if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `abstract` keyword forbids inctances creation (in order to create an instance one has to inherit from abstract class), however, *abstract* classes can have *static* methods e.g.

```
  // abstract: there's no sence in creating an instance of this class
  abstract class MathLibrary {
    // private: there's no sence in inheriting from this class
    private MathLibrary() {}

    // Gamma function
    public static double gamma(double value) { ... }
    ...
  }
```

please note, that when in Java `abstract final class` is not allowed, in C# `abstract sealed class` is `static class`:

```
  // C# static == abstract sealed
  public static class MathLibrary {
    // Gamma function 
    public static double Gamma(double value) { ... }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: [Technically possible != useful] there are better options to do this

Comment: point taken, but can this be considered a good practice ?

Comment: I personally prefer to use well known design patterns. This helps to get your code clean and structured and makes it easier to understand for other developers. so my personal vote is for the patterns instead doing abstract classes + static methods. beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer :** 
The **one and only reason** for creating `Abstract` Classes is to **inherit** them.

**Note :** This is why we **can't** creat a class or method using a combinaison of the `abstract` and `final` keywords because a `final` class cannot be subclassed.

Comment: I never mentioned the final keyword, I was just wondering what tells us good practice about the presence of abstract classes without inheriting methods in a OO program

Comment: i mentionned the final keyword to explain the logic of the abstract class : they **have to be extended** or there are no sense or raison for there existence :)

Comment: All right, I see :-)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, they have no use, since they can only be used when inherited.

Neither would it be of use to transform them into non-abstract classes, since ... You're not using them.

An abstract class is a blueprint to build on, it shouldn't be able to be instantiated. Maybe somewhere there is an anonymous class extending it?
But being there, means they can be used in the future, so deleting them might not be the good idea you're after, either.

Answer (score 0):

well, practically for me there is no reason to do so.
Any case I can imagine right now it would be better to use other ways/design-patterns like singleton, utility, etc..

Maybe you can use them as template to inherit during runtime by reflection etc... (but this would be inheritance as well).

Comment: That won't work.  If a class is `abstract`, you cannot make the singleton instance.  And the JVM will not permit you to make an instance of an abstract class using reflection.

Comment: Thats not what I said! I said that INSTEAD of doing abstract class with static methods it would be better to use a NORMAL class with singleton/utillity pattern. Thanks for the vote;)

Comment: wasn´t my aim but "Thanks man" :D have a nice day..

Answer (score 0):

> "non-inherited abstract classes"

That completely defeats the whole point of abstract classes. The idea of abstract classes is to be a blue print for OTHER CLASSES to be build on.

For example, you can build a Car abstract class, then inherit from that class to create diffrent Car Brands classes that automatically have everything that Car has, but each Brand is different. This way you avoid writing all the instance variables and methods that you could have written in Car in each Car Brand.

Also keep in mind, that you cannot create a Car instance, because its impossible for a a car not to have a brand, so it make sense to make Car abstract.

Comment: that's precisely my point.
It completely defeats the whole point of an abstract class, so can it be considered a bad practice ?